# How to get type of reminder of Google Calendar Event object?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm tring to parse object of Google Calendar Event. It`s event have a reminder with type "email". But looking over all fields of this object, the field  I did not find the type of reminder. It has "useDefault" paramets only. How I can to get the type of reminder?

P.S: I can add the reminder for event from my application using Google calendar API, and it`s like:

```
EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();
reminder.setMinutes(5);
reminder.setMethod("email");

Event.Reminders eRem = new Event.Reminders();
List<EventReminder> reminders = new ArrayList<>();
reminders.add(reminder);
eRem.setOverrides(reminders);
eRem.setUseDefault(false);

event.setReminders(eRem);
```

But, unfortunately, I cant to do a this task upside-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `reminders.overrides[].method`
It returns the type of reminder: `email, sms or popup`

You can see the documentation here: [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events)